# Auto - sorting date in microsoft Excel 2016

Tags: excel, list, sorting, date, excel-formula

I'm trying in excel something very simple but the answer seems more difficult?

At work we created an excel file and from left to right we can fill in details.

For example:

```
Date EmployeeName Status Comments
```

But I want that all cases are being automatically sorted by date. And then from the date of today and future ( explain this later at second ).

So for example today is 27 march 2020.

```
Case1: 1 april 2020  / EmployeeName / Status(open) / commments  
Case2: 2 april 2020  / Employeename / Status(closes ) / comments
```

Now I fill in a new date lets say 29 march 2020. This should automatically pop up above 1 April 2020. However you need to manually click on the sorting table.

Second what if there are cases from before 27 march ( today's date ) can you make them disappear to the bottom of the list? Or in another tab in excel?

Comment: You will want VBA for this in a Worksheet_Change event.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that the easiest solution would be to write an if(...) statement to fulfill those terms in moving the selected dates. For sorting the dates I would recommend to have the date format in dd/mm/yyyy. So it would read 27/03/2020, instead of 27 March 2020. I find the default sorting of excel to work better with the number sequence in that format when sorting (ascending and/or descending) dates.